# Problem of perspective in probablilities

Tags: probability

If a person throws a die twice the probability of two sixes coming up is 1/6 x 1//6=1/36.  The probability, from his perspective, of the next throw being a six is 1/(6x6x6)=216. But a second person throwing the same die for the first time thinks the probability of a six is 1/6.  How can the same event,throwing the die, have a probability of 1/216 for one person and 1/6 for the second.  History of the throws appears to have a role in the probabilities for the first person, but not the second. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

You noticed already that intuitively the setup doesn't make sense—dice are memoryless. So somewhere, there's a mistake in the reasoning. Recall how conditional probabilities work.

For person 1, sure, the probability of *three sixes* is (1/6)^3. But now they're asked to consider the probability of three sixes *given that they've already rolled two sixes*.

$$
p(6 \mid 6, 6) = \frac{p(6, 6, 6)}{p(6, 6, \cdot)} = \frac{(1/6)^3}{\sum_{i=1}^6(1/6)^3} = \frac{1}{6}
$$

The *conditional* probability the same as what person 2 observes, which is independent of previous rolls.